# Dataframe.to_json() not rendering all arguments (pandas)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with the .to_json() function in pandas. I have a dataframe that includes a python object, strings and integers but when I want to convert this dataframe into a JSON document, it simply does not include all parameters of the python object. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(self.pre_company)):
        id_ = self.pre_company.index.values[i]
        code = self.pre_company.iloc[i][0]
        name = self.pre_company.iloc[i][1]
        group = self.pre_company.iloc[i][2]
        try:
            cdf = self.country.loc[self.pre_company.iloc[i][5]]
            country = Country(self.pre_company.iloc[i][5], cdf[0], cdf[1], cdf[2], cdf[3])
        except KeyError:
            country = None
        town = self.pre_company.iloc[i][4]
        company = {'Country': country, 'Code': code, 'Name': name, 'Group': group, 'Town': town}
        new_row = pd.DataFrame(company, index=[id_])
        if i == 0:
            self.company = new_row
        else:
            self.company = pd.concat([company, new_row])
        del new_row
    del self.pre_company

    data2 = self.company.to_json(orient="records")
    with open('test2.json', 'w') as out:
        for i in data2:
            out.write(str(i))
```

And for the first line, I get this result:

```
{"Country":{"a2code":"FR","ccTLD":".fr","officialName":"The French Republic"},"Code":"blah","Name":"blahblah","Group":"GROUP","Town":"town"}
```

Do you have any idea why is the function not completely working ?
PS: I use CSV input file to get my data into dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem: I just had to add a to_dict() function to my python objects which just writes the object in a dict (the way I wanted) and the I add this class at the end of my python object file:

```
class CompanyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
       """
       Encodes the object
       :param self: the encoder itself
       :param obj: the object to encode
       :return: the encoded object
       """
       if isinstance(obj, Company):
          return obj.to_dict()
       else:
          return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

And to convert my object to a dict I used this lines (btw I need to create the object before using this:

```
company = Company(id_, code, name, group, country, town)
self.company.append(company.to_dict())
with open(path, 'w') as out:
    out.write(InvoiceLineEncoder().encode(self.company))
```